# Serializing Camera State in ThreeJS

Tags: serialization, 3d, three.js

What is the best way to serialize (or save or marshal) the state of the camera in a ThreeJS scene, and then un-serialize (or load or unmarshal) the camera later?

Right now I am saving the x, y, z coordinates of the camera's position, up, and (Euler angle) rotation fields. Later I try to restore this camera with calls to `position.set()`, `up.set()`, and `rotation.set()`, and then follow-up with a call to `updateProjectionMatrix()`. I assume the default Euler angle rotation order is the same when serializing and un-serializing.

Is this correct?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would suggest instead storing the camera's matrix. This encompasses the entire transformation on the camera, including position, rotation and scaling.

Serializing:

```
const cameraState = JSON.stringify(camera.matrix.toArray());
// ... store cameraState somehow ...
```

Deserializing:

```
// ... read cameraState somehow ...
camera.matrix.fromArray(JSON.parse(cameraState));
// Get back position/rotation/scale attributes
camera.matrix.decompose(camera.position, camera.quaternion, camera.scale);
```

Comment: I would need to store the serialized matrix in a database, do you have any suggestions about the approximate size of a matrix?

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer did not work for me, instead I came up with the following solution:

1. To save: serialize the x, y and z properties of camera.position and camera.rotation.
2. To reload: deserialize the above 6 params. And reassign them, for example:

   ```
     camera.position.x = saved.position.x;
   ```
3. call `camera.updateProjectionMatrix()` to re-calculate the projection matrix.